# How to show a popup modal on page load in React js functional component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

How to show a popup modal on page load in React js functional component.basically when the page loads the popup or modal should be visible automatically without any click

Answer (score 1):

Most modals will have a prop to specify whether or not the modal should be open. You can simply set this to `true` on initialization.

Consider an example using a `Dialog` from the React UI library MUI:

```
const SimpleDialog = (props) =>
{
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)

  return (
    <Dialog open = {open}>
      <DialogTitle>Title</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>...</DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

The `open` prop of the `Dialog` is based on the value of the state variable, which is initialized as `true`. You can change this value as needed through various `Dialog` actions. To learn more about MUI Dialogs, see the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/).

For information on `useState`, see the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: Cool i think this could work !! Thank you so much !!

Comment: @ShreyashGiri Glad it helped! Please accept this answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        modalState: true
    };

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
}

handleShow() {
    this.setState({ modalState: !this.state.modalState });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={"modal fade" + (this.state.modalState ? " show d-block" : " d-none")} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title">My Profile</h5>
                            <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                                <span>&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">...</div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleShow}>Close</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

Comment: Thank you for your approach, but this is class based component i need it in Fucnctional component ( React Hooks ).